# Convergence of positivity preserving operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces and $Z = L(C_b(X), C_b(Y))$ be the set of linear operators from $C_b(X)$ to $C_b(Y)$, where $C_b(X)$ and $C_b(Y)$ are the sets of continuous real valued bounded functions on $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

An operator $T \in Z$ is called positivity preserving iff

$$f(x) \geq 0 \ \text{for all x} \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad Tf(x) \geq 0 \ \text{for all} \ x \in X.$$

> Let $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of linear operators in $Z$
>   such that $S_{n + 1} - S_n$ is positivity preserving for each $n \in
>  \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in
>   operator norm iff $(S_n1)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in
>   $\sup$-norm, where $1$ is the constant function $x \longmapsto 1$.

**What I did so far.** It was a hint in the exercise that we first should show that each positivity preserving $T \in Z$ is automatically continuous and that furthermore, $\| T \| = \| T1 \|_{\infty}$, where $1$ is again the constant function $x \longmapsto 1$. I was able to show the continuity, more exactly I was able to show that $\| T \| \leq \| T1 \|_{\infty}$. I wasn't able to show "$\geq$", and I am furthermore not sure, whether the backwards inequality is true.

**Question.** If $\| T \| \leq \| T1 \|_{\infty}$ is true, then I think it is more or less clear to show the "$\Longrightarrow$" in the exercise with the $(S_n)$. But how could one show the other direction? If $\| T \| = \| T1 \|_{\infty}$ holds, the other direction would be also clear but I can't see why $\| T \| \geq \| T1 \|_{\infty}$ should be true.

Comment: The topologies on $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are not induced by norms, so $L(C(X), C(Y))$ does not have a natural norm. What operator norm are you looking at?

Comment: I did not really thought about this and it is not furthermore described in the exercise. Is there a "most natural" choice we could use?

Comment: I would check the text, it may be that you are looking at $C_b(X)$ and $C_b(Y)$, the spaces of bounded continous functions. The supremum norm is well defined on these sets.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is not written in my text, but we should assume this. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hint asks you to show $\|T\|=\|T1\|_\infty$ for positive operators.

Note first that $\|1\|_\infty=1$ so that $\|T\| =\| T\|\  \|1\|_\infty ≥ \|T1\|_\infty$ by sub-multiplicativity of the operator norm. Further since $T$ is positive and $\|f\|_\infty\pm f$ is a positive function for any $f$ you have that
$$T(\|f\|_\infty\  1 \pm f)\ (x) = \|f\|_\infty T(1)\ (x) \pm T(f)\ (x)≥0$$
for all $x$ in $Y$. In particular $|T(f)\ (x)| ≤ \|f\|_\infty \ |T(1)\ (x)| ≤ \|f\|_\infty \ \|T1\|_\infty$ for all $x$, implying $\|T(f)\|_\infty ≤ \|T1\|_\infty \ \|f\|_\infty$ for all $f$, giving $\|T\|≤\|T1\|_\infty$.

Now how does this equality help? Well if $S_{n+1}-S_n$ is positive then so is
$$S_n-S_m = \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} S_{k+1}-S_k$$
for all $n>m$, since that is a sum of positive operators. In particular if $S_n1$ converges it must be Cauchy and then $\|S_n-S_m\|=\|(S_n-S_m)1\|_\infty$ is Cauchy. Since $L(C_b(X),C_b(Y))$ is complete this implies that $S_n$ converges in operator norm.

On the other hand if $S_n$ converges in operator norm you have that $S_n1$ must converge indepent of any additional assumptions.

Comment: You use the term "positive" operator. For me, a positive operator $A$ on a Hilbert space is one which fulfills $\langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$. Do the notions of "positivity preserving" and "positive" coincide in some sense or is it just notation?

Comment: They coincide. Your vector spaces $C_b(X), C_b(Y)$ each have a positive cone and an operator is called positive if it sends the positive cone to the positive cone, ie it preserves the property that an element is positive. The definition on $B(H)$ for $H$ a Hilbert space is slightly different, because there are no positive elements of $H$, rather you are defining a positive cone on $B(H)$ for which other maps $B(H)\to V$ can be positive (for example positive linear maps $\omega: B(H)\to\Bbb C$ with $\omega(\Bbb1)=1$ are called states).